# ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Error converting data type nvarchar to int. (8114) (SQLExecDirectW)')

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pyodbc

I am trying use `pyodbc` execute a Stored Procedures

> ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL
>   Server]Error converting data type nvarchar to int. (8114)
>   (SQLExecDirectW)') with the User_id number field.

Here is my code:

```
jsonData = json.loads(data)
user_id = jsonData['user']['id']
Sreenname = jsonData['user']['screen_name']
name = jsonData['user']['name']


con.execute("exec sp_insertintoalltable user_id,Sreenname,name")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `con.execute()` statement is not automatically picking the `user_id`, `Sreenname` and `name` variables from Python; you need to pass those in explicitly, using bind parameters:

```
con.execute("exec sp_insertintoalltable ?, ?, ?", (user_id, Sreenname, name))
```

Comment: thank you i'm now getting 'str' object is not callable as and error

Comment: @KevoniaTomlinson: did you include the comma after the query string? The `(user_id, Sreenname, name)` tuple is a second argument to the `con.execute()` method.

Comment: how to pass an inout parameter in stored procedures using pypyodbc

Comment: @RavinderBaid: presumably the same way you pass in parameters when creating usisng `SELECT` or `INSERT` or `UPDATE`. See the [pyodbc wiki](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Calling-Stored-Procedures) for examples; the pypyodbc library won't work any different there, I don't think.